# Django delete records missing after syncing

Tags: django

I have a Django table that syncs data with a external API. When data is added / updated there is no problem with the sync but how can I detect data has been deleted and remove it from the Django  table. For the record during each sync I am dealing with a lot of data.

Comment: Does the API tell you what was added or updated? I don't see any solution other than for it to also tell you what was deleted.

Comment: It doesnt. I guess the only way would be for me to compare the primary keys of what I have with what I get now ?